# I don't know how to do an array to store for each semester the details. I am supposed to create a subclass of the class Student

Tags: java, inheritance

The question wants me to do:

- An array of Finance called financeRecord to store the details
  of the payments for each semester.

This is my code

```
package lab5;

class Student_U extends Student {

public String student_name;
private String studentID;
public int student_age;


private byte currentSemester;
private byte TotalFinanceRecord;
private String cohort;

public Student_U() {
    
    student_name = " ";
    studentID = " ";
    student_age = 0;
    currentSemester = 1;
    TotalFinanceRecord = 0;
    cohort = " ";
}


public Student_U(String student_name, String studentID, int student_age, 
        String course, String year,
        String section, String subject, String student_name2,
        String studentID2, int student_age2,
        byte currentSemester, byte totalFinanceRecord, String cohort) {
    super(student_name, studentID, student_age, course, year,
    section, subject);
    student_name = student_name2;
    studentID = studentID2;
    student_age = student_age2;
    this.currentSemester = currentSemester;
    TotalFinanceRecord = totalFinanceRecord;
    this.cohort = cohort;
}

public String getStudent_name() {
    return student_name;
}

public void setStudent_name(String student_name) {
    this.student_name = student_name;
}

public String getStudentID() {
    return studentID;
}

public void setStudentID(String studentID) {
    this.studentID = studentID;
}

public int getStudent_age() {
    return student_age;
}

public void setStudent_age(int student_age) {
    this.student_age = student_age;
}

public byte getCurrentSemester() {
    return currentSemester;
}

public void setCurrentSemester(byte currentSemester) {
    this.currentSemester = currentSemester;
}

public byte getTotalFinanceRecord() {
    return TotalFinanceRecord;
}

public void setTotalFinanceRecord(byte totalFinanceRecord) {
    TotalFinanceRecord = totalFinanceRecord;
}

public String getCohort() {
    return cohort;
}

public void setCohort(String cohort) {
    this.cohort = cohort;
}

public void initStudent() {
        
}

public void print() {
    System.out.print("Student name: " + student_name + " ");
    System.out.print("\nMatric No: " + studentID + " ");
    System.out.print("\nAge: " + student_age + " ");
    System.out.print("\nCurrent Semester: " + currentSemester + " ");
    System.out.print("\nCohort: " + cohort + " ");
    
    System.out.println();
}
}
```

Please help me fix my code I would appreciate it so much.
This is my lab assignment which needs to be submitted by tomorrow.

Comment: Which part of the task are you having problems with? How to create an array in Java?

Comment: yes, to create an array like how the question wants.

Comment: Did you try reading any basic materials about Java? "how to create an array in Java?" - this shouldn't be too hard to find in Google. Ability to search for answers to your problems is one of the most important in programming.

Comment: sorry, I'm new to Java and I don't really understand what the question wants. thanks though.

Answer (score 0):

You could try this, but it's also better to review standard java concepts (arrays, classes, etc). After, just adapt your code as suitable.

```
public class Finance  extends Student
{
    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        
        Finance f1 = new Finance("Student_1");
        System.out.println(f1);
        f1.setPayment(1, 10);
        System.out.println(f1);
        f1.setPayment(2, 10.77);
        System.out.println(f1);
        Student s2 = new Student("Student 2");
        Finance f2 = new Finance(s2);
        f2.setPayment(2, 88.77);
        System.out.println(f2);
    }
    Double finaceRecord[] = new Double[3];
    private void initPayment()
    {
        for(int i=0;i<finaceRecord.length;i++)
        {
            finaceRecord[i]=0.0;
        }
    }
    public Finance(Student s)
    {
        super(s.name);
        initPayment();
    }
    public Finance(String name)
    {
        super(name);
        initPayment();
    }
    //store first or second
    public void setPayment(int i, double d)
    {
        if(d<=0) return;
        if(i==1)
        {
            finaceRecord[i] = d;
        }
        else
        {
            finaceRecord[2] = d;
        }
        finaceRecord[0] = finaceRecord[2] + finaceRecord[1];
    }
    
    public String toString()
    {
        return "name="+super.name+", Total Paid="+finaceRecord[0]+","
                + " Sem1="+finaceRecord[1]+", Sem2="+finaceRecord[2];
    }
    
}
```

...

```
public class Student
{
    String name;
    int Semester;
    Student(String name)
    {
        this.name = name;
        this.Semester = 1;
    }
}
```

Ouptut

```
name=Student_1, Total Paid=0.0, Sem1=0.0, Sem2=0.0
name=Student_1, Total Paid=10.0, Sem1=10.0, Sem2=0.0
name=Student_1, Total Paid=20.77, Sem1=10.0, Sem2=10.77
name=Student 2, Total Paid=88.77, Sem1=0.0, Sem2=88.77
```

Answer (score 0):

from what I understand you are supposed to create an array of Finance type

```
Finance []financeRecord = new Finance[totalFinanceRecord];
```

and then you can access the values of Finance class

```
financeRecord[indexNumber].methodName();
```